# Google Sheet Data and Pie Chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I need to show on a pie chart the data in Column B as a % of data in Column A  How can I do that?
The chart calculates the data in Column A as a % of the total sum of column A.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. We expect that people search this site before asking a question. In this case, the question was closed as a duplicate of a couple of previous questions. If none of them meet your needs, please [edit] the question, add some sample data, and describe what stops you from getting the result that you are looking for. Remember that Google Sheets has a Help menu and a tool called Explore located in the Tools menu.